# get magento module config data in Observer

Tags: magento

I created a module with an observer for the sales module with event hook ‘sales_order_shipment_save_after’ ,

My module has the following files

1. Company/Modulename/etc/config.xml
2. Company/Modulename/etc/system.xml
3. Company/Modulename/Model/Observer.php

there are four fields in the modules admin configuration fields
I want to get those saved data in the Observer class.

using **$this->getConfigData(’password’);** gives a

> Call to undefined method

error
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Magento uses a static method on the global `Mage` application object to get configuration values

```
$config = Mage::getStoreConfig('section_name/group/field'); //value
$config = Mage::getStoreConfig('section_name/group'); //array
```

Comment: The group feature is a huge bonus as you can Mage::log($config) and see what all the options are and if you have labelled them properly - thanks for that!

Comment: Your tutorials related to Magento are awesome. Helps a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

An amendment to **Alan's completely correct answer.**

Along with `path` as first parameter, `getStoreConfig` also accepts `storeid` as second parameter(optional).

Well, this is useful when you want to retrieve store-wise values.

Alan has mentioned this point in his own [tutorial](http://alanstorm.com/magento_loading_config_variables). I guess, he has not mentioned here just because OP has not mentioned this requirement in his question.

Please refer [this](http://freegento.com/doc/d8/dcb/class_mage.html#39fabcc2c75f6dcf35459ad632775c85)

Answer (score 0):

In a shipment module I can use `$this->getConfigDat`a for fields in `system.xml`, but in another kind of modules sometimes not, e.g. extends `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`, than I must use getStoreConfig. So the answer is you don't have to use always getStoreConfig. But I don't know why ...

Answer: getConfigData is just defined in a shipment class and uses getStoreConfig too. A little confusing that some functions are extra defined and unneeded in fact ...